# Building and installing MPI wrappers of Valgrind

Tags: debugging, mpi, cluster-computing, valgrind, mpich

I am following the official [documentation of Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.mpiwrap.build) regarding the MPI wrappers, but in my case it is not working as it is expected.

I have downloaded [Valgrind 3.11.0](http://valgrind.org/downloads/) in my machine and I have started the configuration with:

> ./configure --prefix=/apps/install/valgrind --with-mpicc=/apps/install/mpich-3.2

Getting this line:

> checking for mpicc... /apps/install/mpich-3.2/bin/mpicc

instead of:

> checking for usable MPI2-compliant mpicc and mpi.h... yes, mpicc

which is the one that appears in the documentation.

Anyway, I have followed the installation with:

> make && make install

However, I have checked the installation tree and I have not found the library *libmpiwrap.so* of my platform which I supposedly need.

Have I forgotten something?

Thank you!